# Laravel 5 File Uploading getClientOriginalExtention does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

when i`m developing file uploading using laravel 5.4 it gives this error.

**Method getClientOriginalExtention does not exist.**

Here is my UploadController.

```
    public function insertFile(){
        $filetitle=Input::get('file_title');
        $file=Input::file('filenam');
    $rules = array(
   'file_title' => 'required',
    'filenam' => 'required|max:20000|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,jpg,png,jpeg'
            );

        $validator = validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if($validator -> fails()){
            $messages=$validator -> messages();
            return Redirect::to('upload')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);

        }
        else if($validator -> passes()){
            if(Input::file('filenam')->isValid()){
                $extention=Input::file('filenam')->getClientOriginalExtention();
                $filename=rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extention;

                $destinationPath='up_file';
                $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'File Uploaded Successfully',
                    'alert-type' => 'success'
                    );

                return Redirect::to('upload')->with($notification);
            }
            else{
                $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'File is not Valid!',
                    'alert-type' => 'error'
                    );

                return Redirect::to('upload')->with($notification);
            }
        }
    }
```

can anyone help me to solve this.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled `getClientOriginalExtension` It will be 's' instead of 't' in extension.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

getClientOriginalExtention() is spelled wrongly. It should be

```
$extention=Input::file('filenam')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```